# Flutter Error: XMLHttpRequest error OR DioError :The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on t network layer

Tags: flutter, dart, http, xmlhttprequest, dio

I am making a api request on instagram server to fetch some data but got error if use http get this Flutter Error: XMLHttpRequest error  or if using dio package get this DioError :The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on t network layer.

i DONT KNOW WHAT IS HAPPENING
I THINK MAY BE THERE ARE HEADERS ERROR

THIS IS MY HEAERS CODE

```
  Map<String, String> getHeader() {
    final Map<String, String> HEADERS = {
      "User-Agent": getRandomUserAgent(),
      "Cookie": "",
      "Accept":
          "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/",
    };

    return HEADERS;
  }

  final userAgents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/19",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/46",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/47",
  ];

getRandomUserAgent() {
    return userAgents[Random().nextInt(userAgents.length)];
  }
```

and this my code when i m using http

```
 fetchPostJson(String postID) async {
    print("Entered in FetchPostJson");
    final postUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + postID;

    print(postUrl);
    fetchFromPage(postUrl, postID);
  }

  Future<Response?> fetchFromPage(String postUrl, String postID) async {
    final headers = getHeader();

    print("HEADERS:  $headers");

    final  apiURL = postUrl;
    print("API URL:  $apiURL");

    final res = await client.head(Uri.parse(apiURL) , headers: headers);
    print(res.body);

    var adapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter();
    adapter.withCredentials = false;
    dio.httpClientAdapter = adapter;
  }
```

i also used dio but get errors

```
fetchPostJson(String postID) async {
    print("Entered in FetchPostJson");
    final postUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + postID;

    print(postUrl);
    pageExist(postUrl, postID);
  }

  Future<Response?> pageExist(String postUrl, String postID) async {
    final headers = getHeader();

    print("HEADERS:  $headers");

    final apiURL = postUrl;
    print("API URL:  $apiURL");

    try {
      // final res = (await dio.head(apiURL,
      //     options: Options(
      //       method: "GET",
      //       headers: headers,
      //       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      //       responseType: ResponseType.json,
      //       sendTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      //       receiveTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      //     )));
          var adapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter();
    adapter.withCredentials = false;

      final res = await dio.request(apiURL,
          options: Options(
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers,
            responseType: ResponseType.json,
            sendTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
            receiveTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
          ));
      print("Response data get $res");
      return null;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response != null) {
        print(e.response?.statusCode);
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I tries making http request with headers with should be done on head method  via https package and dio package but got errors, and i was expecting a response from the server